# What is the significance of "as of this day"?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-toldot

> ‏"מכרה כיום את בכורתך לי" (בראשית כה לא)‏

Translated as: Sell me as of this day your birthright

What do the words "as of this day" mean?

Answer (score 4):

Different interpretations that I've seen (not sourced yet):

- "Sell it to me 'like day'" - just as the daytime is light and clear, so too the sale should be a "clear" sale.
- "Sell it to me 'as of today'" - as of this moment, I will have the rights of the firstborn.
- "Sell it to me 'like it was today'" - I should be the firstborn, as I acted like the oldest today in providing food for you.

Answer (score 2):

Ramban cites Onkelos: ke'yom dilhain, since the inheritance would only take place on the death of Yitzchok, 'today' refers to that future day